# dockerd init script in fedora

Tags: shell, docker, daemon, init, fedora-25

I need to start `dockerd` during system boot in Fedora 25.

I have installed `docker-engine` in Fedora 25 Server Edition.

**Docker version:**

```
Client:
 Version:      1.13.0
 API version:  1.25
 Go version:   go1.7.3
 Git commit:   49bf474
 Built:        Tue Jan 17 09:58:06 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:      1.13.0
 API version:  1.25 (minimum version 1.12)
 Go version:   go1.7.3
 Git commit:   49bf474
 Built:        Tue Jan 17 09:58:06 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
 Experimental: false
```

I have stored docker file via custom location, so i used to start **dockerd** for below method

```
dockerd -g /u01/docker
```

I see this init scripts  [init1](https://gist.github.com/onjin/5982766) and [init2](https://gist.github.com/petruisfan/c23d4a24594a0a02176f)  But, they only start the docker, **i need to start dockerd with custom location**

Like:

```
dockerd -g /u01/docker
```

How can I change that github init script, or can you suggest how to write a new one?

Answer (score 1):

I find out solution myself

I find out default docker.service file and change to our custom location  path

I added this line `ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -g /u01/docker` instead of `ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd`

**docker.service:**

```
    [Unit]
    Description=Docker Application Container Engine
    Documentation=https://docs.docker.com
    After=network.target firewalld.service

    [Service]
    Type=notify
    # the default is not to use systemd for cgroups because the delegate issues still
    # exists and systemd currently does not support the cgroup feature set required
    # for containers run by docker
    ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -g /u01/docker
    ExecReload=/bin/kill -s HUP $MAINPID
    # Having non-zero Limit*s causes performance problems due to accounting overhead
    # in the kernel. We recommend using cgroups to do container-local accounting.
    LimitNOFILE=infinity
    LimitNPROC=infinity
    LimitCORE=infinity
    # Uncomment TasksMax if your systemd version supports it.
    # Only systemd 226 and above support this version.
    #TasksMax=infinity
    TimeoutStartSec=0
    # set delegate yes so that systemd does not reset the cgroups of docker containers
    Delegate=yes
    # kill only the docker process, not all processes in the cgroup
    KillMode=process

    [Install]
    WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

After that I run

```
sytemctl daemon-reload
systemctl enable docker.service 
systemctl start docker.service
```

Now, docker start while system boot.